# How to Redirect a User to new Page(View) while submitting PartialView's data through Ajax and there is an error while processing the Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am working a small MVC application. and have a screen(view) which has three Partial views and each partial view each some textboxes and buttons. I submit each partial view information to server using Ajax.BeginRequest which calling to a controller/action.

==================Partial View 1======

Submit on a Button click

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action1", "contoller1", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() 
     { 
         OnFailure= "OnFailure()", 

     }
))
```

==================Partial View 2=======

Submit on a Button click

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action2", "contoller2", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() 
     { 
         OnFailure= "OnFailure()", 

     }
))
```

==================Partial View 3=======

Submit on a Button click

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("action3", "contoller3", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() 
     { 
         OnFailure= "OnFailure()", 

     }
))
```

==========================================

the event OnFailure() handled in a Javascript file

```
function OnFailure()
{
    Window.location.href="/Error/Index/-1"   
}
```

( Please ignore syntax..I have code in different machine)

Requirement: If there is any error while processing any Partialview (1/2/3) data on server side on button click. We should be redirecting user to a completely a new friendly error page.

what I did:
`onFailure` event/function of `Ajax.BeginReques`t, I am using above code to redirect to a Index view of Error controller.

/Error/Index shows

> "There is an Error while processing your request, Please try again or contact administration.."

**Actual Output:**

If submit `PartialView2` data and there is any error. The error message display in `partialView` like this.

=================Partial View 1=======

==================Partial View 2=======

> "There is an Error while processing your request, Please try again or contact administration.."
>   ==================Partial View 3=======

**Expected Output:**

Then user should be redirect to a different page completely, if there is any error while processing any `partialView` through ajax.

**
------Error\Index-1-----

### There is an Error while processing your request, Please try again or contact administration..

**

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: changed from windows to window in OnFailure() function as per Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a typo from adding the code to the question, but if not, it will definitely be a problem. In your `OnFailure` function, you're redirecting with:

```
Windows.location.href="/Error/Index/-1"
```

The JS object name is `window`, not `Windows`, or you can just leave it off completely, i.e.:

```
location.href="/Error/Index/-1"
```

Comment: Except catching the typo error( which i have already mention,could be), your reply is not relevant to my question.

Comment: How is it not relevant. On failure, previously, it was setting a non-existing member, which has no function. After the change, it will now actually change the href member, and the browser should redirect as a result. Although, bear in mind that this is not a true redirect, but merely a GET for the URL you're setting there.

Comment: it is still redirecting..But that is not I am expecting, Please look actual vs expected output in my above question.  if i had used "Windows" then i should have received a javascript error and i should never redirected in that case.